# Trying to add Spring Mobile to my current Spring MVC Project

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-mobile

I am trying to add Spring Mobile to my current Spring MVC Project but I keep getting the following error:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.mobile.device.Device]: Specified class is an interface
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:894)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

root cause

org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.mobile.device.Device]: Specified class is an interface
    org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:101)
    org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:136)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:81)
    org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:102)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:75)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:162)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:123)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:100)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:604)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:565)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

Here is my controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/ask")
class IndexController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(IndexController.class);

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String displayRequestPage(Device device, SitePreference sitePreference) {

        logger.info("SitePreference : " + sitePreference);
        logger.info("Device : " + device);

        String page = "index";

        if (device.isMobile()) {
            logger.info("Hello mobile user!");
            page = page  + "-mobile";
        } else if (device.isTablet()) {
            logger.info("Hello tablet user!");
            page = page  + "-tablet";
        } else {
            logger.info("Hello desktop user!");
        }
        return "index";
     }


}
```

and here is my WebConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages= {"com.johnathanmsmith.mvc.web"})
public class WebMVCConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String MESSAGE_SOURCE = "/WEB-INF/classes/messages";

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebMVCConfig.class);

    @Bean
    public  ViewResolver resolver() {
        UrlBasedViewResolver url = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
        url.setPrefix("views/");
        url.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        url.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return url;
    }

    @Bean
    public LiteDeviceDelegatingViewResolver liteDeviceAwareViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver delegate = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        delegate.setPrefix("views/");
        delegate.setSuffix(".jsp");
        LiteDeviceDelegatingViewResolver resolver = new LiteDeviceDelegatingViewResolver(delegate);
        resolver.setMobilePrefix("mobile/");
        resolver.setTabletPrefix("tablet/");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean(name = "messageSource")
    public MessageSource configureMessageSource() {
        logger.debug("setting up message source");
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename(MESSAGE_SOURCE);
        messageSource.setCacheSeconds(5);
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        SessionLocaleResolver lr = new org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver();
        lr.setDefaultLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
        return lr;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        logger.debug("setting up resource handlers");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/").addResourceLocations("/resources/**");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        logger.debug("configureDefaultServletHandling");
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(final InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new LocaleChangeInterceptor());
        registry.addInterceptor(new DeviceResolverHandlerInterceptor());
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleMappingExceptionResolver simpleMappingExceptionResolver() {
        SimpleMappingExceptionResolver b = new SimpleMappingExceptionResolver();

        Properties mappings = new Properties();
        mappings.put("org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound", "p404");
        mappings.put("org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException", "dataAccessFailure");
        mappings.put("org.springframework.transaction.TransactionException", "dataAccessFailure");
        b.setExceptionMappings(mappings);
        return b;
    }
}
```

I dont know what it can be.. If you would like to clone the project I have it on github at
**git@github.com:JohnathanSmith/springmvc-mobile.git**

Comment: In the Spring Mobile docs, it mentions that if you want to pass the current device as an argument to your controller, you need to configure the DeviceWebArgumentResolver: [Obtaining a reference to the current device](http://static.springsource.org/spring-mobile/docs/1.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-mobile-device-web-argument-resolver).

Comment: @SJS did this answer solve your problem? Adding a DeviceWebArgumentResolver works perfectly for me.